# Literally grep the only word in a line

Tags: grep

I know `grep -F` can search for literal strings, but I want to do something like

```
while read word; do
  grep -F "^$word$" FILE;
done < wordlist
```

i.e. the words need to be treated literally, at the same time, `^` and `$` conditions need to be satisfied.

How to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-x` option:

```
grep -x -F word file
```

`-x` will "[consider only input lines that use all characters in the line ... to match an entire fixed string](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)".

Comment: thanks, i ll accept this in 10 mins. so there is no generalized way to treat some part of pattern as regex and some part as literal, is it?

Comment: Not other than escaping the special characters, no.